# ohm's law and power equation

Tags: equation

I have a question about electricity. I know that transmitting power over long distances is better in AC. I also heard that the voltage needs to be high to reduce losses. I want to calculate this for myself.

Imagine, there is a windmill that produces 100 kW of power. This 100 kW needs to be transported over a 1 km wire that has 1 ohm of resistance. We can transfer this 100kW of power at 1kV or 10kV. But we are going to look which one is most beneficial.

When we send the 100kW at 1kV:

- This means we have 100A (Power/Voltage) with a loss of 10kW (Current^2*Resistance).

When we send the 100kW at 10 kV:

- This means we have 10A (Power/voltage) with a loss of 0.1kW (Current^2*Resistance).

This proves that the losses are less when the voltage is high than when the voltage is low. However, I noticed something odd. When we send the 100kW at 1 kV I calculated that the current is 100A via the power equation (100 000 / 1 000). But when I calculate the current via ohm's law I get 1kA (1 000 * 1). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is not one ohm of resistance.  It is one ohm of resistance for every 100 meters or whatever distance.  It isn't just resistance either - there is capacitance between nearby wires and inductance from nearby wires  - all three together is called reactance.  So AC is better not because of the resistance (which is the same for AC and DC) but because of the capacitance and inductance which cannot build up if the current changes direction fast enough.

Comment: If you get different answers from I = V/R and I = P/V then one of your assumptions is wrong - the wire clearly doesn't have one ohm of resistance.  If you equate the two equations you can solve for R:  R = P/V^2  = 100kW/1kV^2 = 0.1 ohms  If it does have one ohm of resistance then either the power or the voltage is wrong and since power is derived from voltage and current (and current is how many electrons can be forced through this resistance by that much voltage) then it would be the power that is wrong.

Comment: You don't say what exactly you calculate with Ohm's law and why do you multiply 1000 with 1, but 1 ohm is the resistance of wire only, and if 1kV and 100A is used, there won't be 1000V drop over the wire resistance, but for the whole load, so according to Ohm's law U=R×I the 100A with 1 ohms causes 100V drop in the wires and 900V is over the load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we send the 100kW at 1 kV I calculated that the current is 100A via the power equation (100 000 / 1 000). But when I calculate the current via ohm's law I get 1kA (1 000 * 1). What am I doing wrong?

Hope forgetting about the load.

The 100 kW is (mostly)  delivered to the load, not to the 1 ohm of the transmission line.

Similarly, the voltage is (mostly) dropped across the load, not across the transmission line.

Answer (score 0):

Ohm's Law:

$$V = IR$$

Electrical power:

$$P = VI = I^2R$$

Electrical power is calculated as voltage times current at an instant of time.

This article

http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2010/ph240/hamerly1/

describes how the efficiency of electrical power transmission increases when the voltage is increased and the current is decreased for a given level of electrical power transmission.

In the past AC was more efficient because electrical power transformers could boost the voltage and reduce the current in high voltage AC transmission lines.

Modern technology can now boost the voltage for DC power transmission and in some cases that new technology is even more efficient than the AC technology.